# More than one result on request with limit 1 sqllite

Tags: sqlite, limit

The result is one line, but there are several people with the same value of the bonus field

```
SELECT Name, bonus
From employees
ORDER by bonus
Limit 1
```

result

> Ivan 100

but it is required that it was

> Ivan 100
> Petr 100

did this, but it seems very confusing to me:

```
SELECT Name, bonus
From employees
Where bonus= (SELECT id From employees ORDER by bonus Limit 1)
```

Comment: Why did you limit the results to 1 row if you want more than 1 row?

Comment: perhaps `SELECT Name,bonus FROM employees WHERE bonus = (SELECT min(bonus) FROM employees);` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite you can achieve that by using RANK or dense_rank window function

```
select name, bonus 
  from (select name, bonus, dense_rank() over(order by bonus desc) dns_rnk from employees) 
 where dns_rnk = 1;
```

In sub-query it will rank employees on bonus and the outer query will filter out unneeded lines.

Comment: Thank you. I just got used to the fact that in another dialect (Jet sql)  it was immediately displayed correctly

Comment: @oivano88 some other databases  have "with ties" clause for that kind of needs. Unfortunately it is not yet implemented in sqlite. Удачи